# How to find $f_1\circ f_2\circ\cdots f_{13}(2),$ where $f_n(x) = \frac{nx+9}{x+3}$

Tags: functions, contest-math, function-and-relation-composition

How to find $f_1\circ f_2\circ\cdots f_{13}(2),$ where $f_n(x) = \frac{nx+9}{x+3}$ in a reasonable amount of time?

I solved this problem through brute forcing, but that took about an hour, and got the final answer $23/11.$ Is there a much quicker way to do this? (The recommended time is 5-10 minutes)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Express $f_n(x) = n + \frac{9-3n}{x+3}$. Then $f_3(x) = 3$, for all $x$. Thus your expression reduces to $f_1(f_2(3))$.

Edit: As cardboard_box notes in the comments, one needs to check that $f_n(x)\neq -3$ for $n\leq 13$ in the above composition (and the appropriate $x$). You can do it as described by cardboard_box.

Comment: No need for "Express... Then... ". $f_3(x)=\frac{3x+9}{x+3}=3$ is the only thing that matters.

Comment: @A.G., I was just about to comment that. You are correct, but it is not as easy to see that $f_n$ will be constant for any $n$ from the original expression (it is, of course, when you are told the fact). This kind of rewriting is natural step for any problem of this kind, as it removes variable from numerator and makes calculations easier. For example, a high school problem might be: "Find all integers $n$ such that $\frac{n+2}{n-3}$ is an integer." That is why I won't go the minimalist route in this case.

Comment: $f_3(-3)$ is undefined, so you'd also need to show that $f_4\circ f_5\circ\cdots f_{13}(2) \neq -3 $.  This can be shown by the fact that $f_n(x)$ is positive for positive $ x, n $.

Comment: @cardboard_box, yes, thank you for mentioning.